# How I will get lacks of dummy customers for Magento test site?

Tags: magento-1.9, performance

As I am working on "Improve Magento site Performance". I want to load lots of data in my test site.

Is there any place where I can get such big data to import into Magento system.

Answer (score 1):

Magento offers and import functionality for customers.
You can go to system->import/export->import and you will find it.
So you just need to create a big csv file or better a set of smaller ones that follow the allowed structure and import them.

Answer (score 1):

I have starred some projects on GitHub that may be useful:

- [Load Test Scenarios for Magento 1 and Magento 2](https://github.com/magecorelab/magento-load-test)
- [LimeSoda Sample Data Generator](https://github.com/LimeSoda/LimeSoda_SampleDataGenerator)
- [Magento Hackathon: Real Big Sample Data](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Real-Big-Sample-Data)
- [Magento Load Testing Database](https://github.com/kalenjordan/magento-load-test)

Hope it helps